# Django Rest Framework - how to get Http header information in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am making a Django-based API and here is my urls.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

api_version = "v1"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/', include( "api."+ api_version +".urls", namespace=api_version )),
]
```

What I want to do is to retrieve API version from http accept header.  I tried to use django.http.HttpRequest module, which didn't do the trick.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access request on `urls.py`, see: [How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

You can configure [versioning](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#versioning-with-rest-framework) on django-rest-framework and get `version` on request object like:

```
class SampleView(APIView):

 def post(self, request, format=None):
     if request.version == '1':
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_410_GONE)
```

Or use `URLPathVersioning` approach.

Comment: I know that I can get the version info in views.py but what I am trying to do is to retrieve it in urls.py.  My current folder structure is api/v1/foo/views.py, api/v2/foo/views.py so I am trying to dynamically include view files in urls.py, based on the http header api version info.

Comment: You can have both urls use same view, but then differentiate code based on request.version

Comment: @joelgoldstick I did not want to add all the versions of view logics in one place but I guess I will have to since it is required to use AcceptHeaderVersioning.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JairHenrique unfortunately my boss wants me to use AcceptHeaderVersioning

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access request in url.py, for your particular scnerio i-e for version,
you can use different url for different version of your api.

like

```
url(r'^v1/', include("api.v1.urls")),
url(r'^v2/', include("api.v2.urls")),
url(r'^v3/', include("api.v3.urls")),
```